# How to know if the address is 64 bit aligned?

Tags: memory

I have an address say hex 0x26FFFF how to check if the given address is 64 bit aligned? I am aware that address should be multiple of 8 in order for 64 bit aligned, so how to make it 64 bit aligned and what are the different ways possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if an address is 64 bits aligned, you just have to check if its 3 least significant bits are null. For instance

```
(ad & 0x7) == 0
```

checks if ad is a multiple of 8.

Addresses are allocated at compile time and many programming languages have ways to specify alignment. For instance, since CC++11 or C11, you can use `alignas()` in C++ or in C (by including stdalign.h) to specify alignment of a variable. Hence

```
alignas(8) char str[24];
```

guarantees that str is 64 bits aligned.

Before the alignas keyword, people used tricks to finely control alignment. For instance, a struct is aligned as its largest field. But there was no way, for instance, to insure that a struct with 8 chars or  struct with a char and an int are 8 bytes aligned. Depending on the situation, people could use padding, unions, etc. This is no longer required and `alignas()` is the preferred way to  control variable alignment.

Dynanically allocated data with `malloc()`  is supposed to be "suitably aligned for any built-in type" and hence is always at least 64 bits aligned.

This can be used to move unaligned data to an aligned address. For instance, if you have a string str at an unaligned address and you want to align it, you just need to `malloc()` the proper size and to `memcpy()` data at the new position.

Note the std::align function in C++. Given a buffer address, it returns the first address in the buffer that respects specific alignment constraints and can be used to find a proper location in a buffer if variable reallocation is required.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check alignment of an address, follow this simple rule;
Since, byte is the smallest unit to work with memory access
A 64 bit address has 8 bytes.
(considering, 1 byte = 8bit)

Therefore,
Log2(n) = Log2(8) = 3 (to know the power)
Where, n is number of bytes.

It means the lower  three bits to be zero, in order to follow the alignment rule.
E.g.
If i have an address, say, 0xC000_0004
Next aligned address would be : 0xC000_0008.
You can verify that following address do not have the lower three bits as zero, those are 
 0xC000_0005
 0xC000_0006
 0xC000_0007
So, after C000_0004 the next 64 bit aligned address is C000_0008.

Thanks